# OpenGL 3.0 (and higher) alpha test based on accumulated alpha value

Tags: opengl

I have a scene in which there are many parallel squares with different semi-transparent textures.

To render them properly, I disable Z-buffer test, enable blending in the following way and render squares from the most distant one to the closest one (i.e. from back to front).

```
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

So each square contribute to the resulting value in the color buffer. Is it possible to render them from front to back and discard a fragment if this fragment does not contribute much to the resulting color (i.e. alpha value in color buffer > some threshold)?

I know there is `discard` command in the fragment shader, but I see no way how I can control blending from the shader.

P.S. I do not know OpenGL terminology much. To be clear, I'll provide an example. Imagine you have a dark optical filter and put it against a wall. The wall will be barely visible (it gives a small contribution to the "rendering"). Put another optical filter in the front of the first one. The wall will not be visible behind those filters. Is there a way in OpenGL to not render that part of the wall which is not visible?

Comment: You would have to render front-to-back (which is possible), but I don't think there's such a thing as destination alpha test.

Comment: Are the textures mostly semi-transparent (like a smoke texture), or are they mostly fully opaque with soft alpha edges (like a foliage texture)? If it's the latter, you might be able to win some performance with a Z pre-pass if there is a huge amount of overdraw. If it's the former, there's no easy answer to my knowledge, because you can't sample the destination alpha from a shader.

Comment: @Stuntddude The textures are mostly semi-transparent. The renderings look like pictures at the bottom of [this](https://github.com/shamazmazum/voxcube) page (now I just draw different densities with different colors).

Comment: For the specific use case of rendering a density map, it will probably be faster to do volumetric ray marching in the fragment shader.

Comment: @Stuntddude how would you render that Z pre-pass? You'd want only opaque fragments to contribute to that Z-pass (otherwise you'll see the transparent parts of geometry occlude stuff behind)

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann You would use the `discard` statement to avoid writing non-opaque pixels to the depth buffer. Should look something like `if (texture(tex, coords).a <= 254.5/255.0) discard;`